# Detecting mesh overlaps of objects inside another object

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh, bvh

How can we detect the overlap between two objects one has been placed inside the other?
I'm writing a placement algorithm and it seems regular BVH mesh overlap doesn't work for this case. Is there a way to detect this overlap?

See the picture:

[image]

Comment: i too wish to know how